# Php Geoplugin not working?

Tags: php, geolocation, location

I have followed all the directions given at:

http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php

Yet my nothing is popping up the page is just blank ( Yes I have it uploaded on my online sever )

```
<?php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
echo "City: ".$city."<br>";
echo "Region: ".$region."<br>";
echo "Country: ".$country."<br>";
?>
```

The only thing that pops up is this

City:

Region:

Country:

With no answers. Help?

Comment: It will not work with Localhost (127.0.0.1) and always give Null. Once you upload same thing on server it will work fine.

Comment: I'm not using local host http://hacks4us.org/x.php It's still showing up. Do you think it might have to do with my server ? I'm signed up with Ipage.

Comment: echo $user_ip what does it return? generally $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; is used for getting client's IP Address.

Comment: I got it! The code was right my sever just had 'allow_url_fopen' off thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @kamlesh.bar thanks, that's why I've been testing for hours to no avail... Doesn't work on localhost. Kinda makes sense....

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=".$user_ip));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array (
'geoplugin_request' => '112.133.198.126',
'geoplugin_status' => 206,
'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.',
'geoplugin_city' => '',
'geoplugin_region' => '',
'geoplugin_areaCode' => '0',
'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '0',
'geoplugin_countryCode' => 'IN',
'geoplugin_countryName' => 'India',
'geoplugin_continentCode' => 'AS',
'geoplugin_latitude' => '20',
'geoplugin_longitude' => '77',
'geoplugin_regionCode' => '',
'geoplugin_regionName' => NULL,
'geoplugin_currencyCode' => 'INR',
'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => '₨',
'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => '₨',
'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '61.62',
)
```

The `city` and `region` fields are blank and only get the `country` value

Answer (score 0):

If geoplugin.net was responding perfectly, then stopped, then you have gone over the free lookup limit of 120 requests per minute.

More often than not, this happens when people's sites get spidered by search engine crawlers, which can very quickly take a site's geoplugin.net lookups to over 120 in a minute.